# Terraform script for ICMP

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

My terraform plan got crashed after adding ICMP options to the script.

My requirement is to give "all" in the type and code for ICMP. The moment I gave, I got a syntax error.

```
            icmp_options 
                    "type" = All
                    "code" = All
```

After referring to multiple links, I found "-1" is used in type & code for "all". the moment i gave the options and gave terraform plan, the terraform crash log got generated.

```
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalValidateResource, err: Warnings: []. Errors: [unexpected EOF]
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: Warnings: []. Errors: [unexpected EOF]
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: unexpected EOF
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalValidateResource, err: Warnings: []. Errors: [connection is shut down]
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: Warnings: []. Errors: [connection is shut down]
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalValidateResource, err: Warnings: []. Errors: [connection is shut down]
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: Warnings: []. Errors: [connection is shut down]
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalValidateResource, err: Warnings: []. Errors: [connection is shut down]
2018/12/15 14:08:32 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: Warnings: []. Errors: [connection is shut down]



Error:
Error: Error running plan: 4 error(s) occurred:

* oci_core_dhcp_options.a-n-dev-db: 1 error(s) occurred:

* oci_core_dhcp_options.a-n-dev-db: unexpected EOF
* oci_core_security_list.a-n-dev-app-1: 1 error(s) occurred:

* oci_core_security_list.a-n-dev-app-1: unexpected EOF
* oci_core_default_dhcp_options.default-dhcp-options-a-vcn: 1 error(s) occurred:

* oci_core_default_dhcp_options.default-dhcp-options-a-vcn: unexpected EOF
* oci_core_security_list.a-n-uat-db-4: 1 error(s) occurred:

* oci_core_security_list.a-n-uat-db-4: unexpected EOF
```

Please advise, what type or code should i use to give "All" in the ICMP.

Answer (score 1):

where did you add `icmp_options`? I'm assuming it was added to resource `oci_core_security_list`. If you specify ICMP as the protocol but omit this object, then all ICMP types and codes are allowed.

so you can configure it like this:

```hcl
resource "oci_core_security_list" "ExampleSecurityList" {
    ingress_security_rules {
        protocol  = 1
        source    = "0.0.0.0/0"
        stateless = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jijin Shaji, Happy New Year, just want to check if you still have the problem or not.